# PHP Upload all file types

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Is it possible to upload file types like ".psd", ".eps", ".zip", ".txt", and so on..?

And, can anyone recommend a PHP based upload handler script which also allows uploads of all kind of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `<input type='file' />` element on submit will allow uploading of all file types that I am aware of. The data will exist in your `$_FILES` super global array in PHP.

You likely will have some restrictions in your `php.ini` file, especially regarding file size.

Comment: Can I change those file size restrictions?

Comment: Yeah. You can change the `MEMORY_LIMIT` value in `php.ini` for a permanent change. You can temporarily override the `php.ini` `MEMORY_LIMIT` by executing PHP's `ini_set( 'MEMORY_LIMIT' );` function. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: @wescrow the `upload_max_filesize` may need changing too, the default is 2M this can only be changed in php.ini or using .htaccess

Comment: @RMcLeod You are absolutely correct. That is actually what I meant to reference. Although, both may need upped depending on their current settings.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to upload anything if you're using the standard file control `<input type='file'>`, its completely indiscriminate.

Obviously it's then down to what you have on your server as to what you can do with the file that's been uploaded,

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the file upload - you should restrict as much as you can, a minimalist approach, bad things can happen, like malicious intent.  Spend time here, http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php, great scripts and commentary on how to handle/best practices.